# Retrieve Data from based on different row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Today with the data from the table

```
ID  Datetime                   Status            Count1  Count2   RNdata
1   2018-01-31 15:30:05.190    Done reading      0       0        1
1   2018-01-31 15:30:05.190    Cancel            1       0        2
1   2018-01-31 15:30:05.190    Not started yet   0       1        3
1   2018-01-31 15:30:05.190    Almost            0       0        4

5   2018-02-06 15:30:07.583    Almost            0       0        1 
5   2018-02-06 15:30:07.583    Cancel            1       0        2

8   2018-01-22 15:30:29.747    Not started yet   0        1       1
8   2018-01-22 15:30:29.747    Cancel            1        0       2
8   2018-01-22 15:30:29.747    Done reading      0        0       3
8   2018-01-22 15:30:29.747    Almost            0        0       4
```

Above it is a sample and in reality it is alot of data row with differnt data.
The only structure data is column RNDATA

Goal:
Requested result below.

```
ID  Datetime                   Status            Count1  Count2   RNdata
1   2018-01-31 15:30:05.190    Done reading      1        1       1
5   2018-02-06 15:30:07.583    Almost            1        0       1 
8   2018-01-22 15:30:29.747    Not started yet   1        1       1
```

I tried to solved but I failed :(

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your failed SQL and explain how the desired output is attained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` :

```
select t.id, t.datetime, tt.Status, 
       sum(Count1) as Count1, sum(Count2) as Count2, min(rndata) as rndata
from table t cross apply (
     select top 1 t1.Status
     from table t1
     where t1.id = t.id
     order by t1.rndata
   ) tt
group by t.id, t.datetime;
```

However, you can also re-express it as via *window* function :

```
select distinct id, datetime, 
      first_value(Status) over (partition by id order by rndata) as Status,
      sum(count1) over (partition by id) as count1,
      sum(count2) over (partition by id) as count2,
      min(rndata) over (partition by id) as rndata
from table t;
```